# Component.GetComponent<T>() is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to turn off the gravity for one instantiated prefab clone, if something in the game happens. I have this:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour   

   public Transform randomcoin;

   private void Start()

      if ( ... ) 
          { randomcoin.GetComponent<Rigidbody>.useGravity = false; }
```

This gives me this error:

```
Component.GetComponent<T>() is a method, which is not valid in the given context
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: A simple typo. You forget `()` after `<Rigidbody>`. That should be `randomcoin.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;`. Voted to close question.

Comment: That's really stupid, sorry! But thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing () in `randomcoin.GetComponent<Rigidbody>`
It should be like this:
`randomcoin.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`

Comment: Omg, that's really stupid. Sorry. But thanks! :)

Comment: just for completeness sake, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Yes I tried to, but I must wait some minutes. I'll do it when its possible!